# What can we use instead of these rejectUnauthorized: false, requestCert: true in React Native?

Tags: node.js, api, http, https, react-native

I am calling a remote API that is working on postman on windows platform but the same is not working on IOS platform in postman.

I have to call that API in React-Native but I am getting error `Network Request failed on IOS`.

I have developed the node Js call and it is working here also but I had to submit these two parameters, these are 
             `rejectUnauthorized: false,
                      requestCert: true,`

Here is my Code that is working in NODE.JS but not in React-Native.

```
var r = request.post('HTTPS://{HOST}/oauth2-api/p/v1/token?scope=TMO_ID_profile associated_billing_accounts associated_customers associated_lines billing_information offer' +
    '&grant_type=client_credentials', {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'Authorization': '{BASIC BASE 64}'
        },
        rejectUnauthorized: false,
        requestCert: true,
    },
    function optionalCallback(err, httpResponse, body) {
        if (err) {
            return console.error(' failed:', err);
        }

          console.log(' Server responded with:', JSON.parse(body));
          requestaccess(JSON.parse(body).token_type + " " + JSON.parse(body).access_token);

    });
```

Only concern is what is the alternative of these two
     `rejectUnauthorized: false,
        requestCert: true,` 
in React-Native?